# How to View .pptx file in android

Tags: android, apache-poi, powerpoint

I wanted know that how to view .pptx powerpoint presentation file from my mobile storage or sdcard in android i used Apache-poi but it did not work on android.

Answer (score 0):

Download OffieSuite 8 or Polaris Office like software and call that pptx file through intent. Have a look [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-any-type-of-file-with-default-intent). See, if that help.